# Corrupted MAC on input. ssh_dispatch_run_fatal:message authentication code incorrect unable to ssh jupyter notebook on remote server

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, server, remote-access

I was trying to connect to my jupyter notebook which is running on my remote server so that I can access it on my local windows machine.

These were the steps that I followed.

On my remote server :

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

Then on my local windows machine

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 *******@**********.de.bosch.com
```

But I am getting an error

```
C:\>ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 *******@**********.de.bosch.com
Corrupted MAC on input.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 10.82.134.38 port 22: message authentication code incorrect
```

However when I tried doing the same thing on Microsoft Ubuntu WSL. I was able to connect successfully and then I was able to connect by typing `jupyter notebook` on cmd.

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 *****@*******.de.bosch.com
The authenticity of host '*****@*******.de.bosch.com (10.82.134.38)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:EMneQnZfl3uyH0xeH+LPnkib4v7lF24qdx5C1QnXkxI.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '*******.de.bosch.com' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password: ******
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/994646/ssh-on-windows-corrupted-mac-on-input and technically off-topic for stackoverflow (see description of ssh tag)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ssh -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 -m hmac-sha2-256 *******@**********.de.bosch.com
```

If you don't get it, execute:

```
ssh -Q mac
```

and replace `hmac-sha2-256` with each one.

Comment: basically add `-m hmac-sha2-256` in your request. so `ssh <host>` becomes `ssh -m hmac-sha2-256 <host>`. It worked for me. thanks @dheerajreddy